# Did Dumbledore's scar adapt to reflect Muggle changes in the London Underground?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

We learn about Dumbledore's scar when he drops Harry off at the Dursleys:

> "Couldn't you do something about it, Dumbledore?"
>
> "Even if I could, I wouldn't. Scars can come in useful. I have one myself above my left knee which is a perfect map of the London Underground.
>
> *(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 1, The Boy Who Lived)*

Plainly this is a light-hearted aside. Although I do find the idea of Dumbledore consulting his knee to work out which station to get off at whilst using the Tube hilarious.

[image: Dumbeldore at train station]

However, the Muggle underground has clearly undergone a number of changes over the years. For instance, [the new Elizabeth Line](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-35640494) will change the structure and layout of the Underground significantly when it becomes operational in 2018. [This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82200/what-did-dumbledore-say-his-scar-on-his-left-knee-was) question deals with the issue a bit but doesn't answer the specifics of how Dumbeldore's scar worked.

**Did Dumbledore's scar change over the years? Is there any indication that scars work this way?**

Comment: The Dark Lord is asking about Dumbledore, we shouldn't tell him......(^_~)(⌒▽⌒)☆

Comment: I've always rather thought Dumbledore's scar shows the London Underground in the same way that Dumbledore saw himself holding socks in the Mirror of Erised.

Comment: In other words, that Dumbledore was being flippant and humorous both times because he didn't want to reveal too much about himself?

Comment: Not exactly the same question. But the answer by @alexwlchan mostly answers your question. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82200/what-did-dumbledore-say-his-scar-on-his-left-knee-was

Comment: If I thought the point was answered in the other question is it likely that I would ask my own question with a link to the original?

Comment: There is nothing at all in the question (or answers) this has been marked as a duplicate of. That question just establishes that it's a map of the London Underground, which says basically nothing. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Well, I don't think this one was really to avoid revealing too much about himself—but it always struck me as being a bit flippant and not entirely truthful.

Comment: [Martha's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/82214/20774) covers this perfectly. *"There's no reason the statement couldn't be literally true, i.e. Dumbledore has a complex scar above his left knee, the lines of which correspond to the lines of a map of the London subway system. The most likely interpretation is thus that Dumbledore is indulging in a bit of hyperbole: the scar consists of intersecting lines, and if you squint just right, you can see similarities between it and a map of the London Underground. It's really not any more complicated than that.*"

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that thought about how scars work in Harry Potter. The other question was wondering *what* Dumbledore's scar is. I know what it is. I'm wondering how it works.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - It doesn't "*work"*. The joke is that in Dumbledore's opionion it closely *resembles* the tube map (e.g. complex and striated), not that it's a **literal representation** of the map.

Comment: @TheDarkLord It would be safe to assume that Hogwarts must have undergone few alterations in design right? For example closure of all hidden paths from Hogwarts to Hogsmeade except one. Marauder's map did not change to reflect those changes. Therefore I doubt such magical maps have the ability to sync themselves with on-going changes.

Comment: @Aegon. The Marauder's Map did have those hidden passageways on it. So it must have adapted when they were built. You may be right that it didn't show the caveins and blockages (if that's what you mean). I dunno, I'm not sure you can put a scar and a map in the same category or say they work the same way.

Comment: @TheDarkLord Or they already existed when the map was created? (Except the one built for Lupin but they knew about it anyways). What the map did not adapt to is the fact that they were closed, that's what I meant. I am not sure about the categorization either but other than Marauder's map, IIRC we don't know any other magical map.

Answer (score 1):

Hate to tell you this, but they really don’t mention Dumbledore’s scar at all after that scene. Therefore, I reserve the right to idly speculate:

There are two possibilities concerning the origin of his scar- magical or non-magical. I mean, we don’t even know that much. Was the scar an honorable wound gained in a fierce battle? Or did he have an accident involving one of those new-fangled muggle bikes?

If it was a non-magical accident, then I’m afraid the scar it stuck the way it is, doomed forever to be inaccurate.

If not, then I suppose it depends on the nature of the magic that inflicted the scar. Harry’s scar was only special because a bit of Voldemort’s soul happened to be in him at the time. If Dumbledore’s scar is shaped like the Underground, then basically it looks like a bunch of squiggly lines, right? I’m not exactly sure how a spell could scar you in such a way, as the only other instances of magic causing scars is when a body part is physically cursed off, like when George loses an ear. Most spells just happen to DO something, like make a tea cup dance or kill you. Unless the spell intentionally was cast to cause a cool scar (like a more concentrated, British version of Sectumsempra, which basically maims you), it would only do it’s desired effect. Maybe some magical animal scarred him, who knows. Either way, it is improbable that the scar was intentionally shaped like London underground, and as it wasn’t associated with it to begin with, it would have no reason to change to account for new routes or whatever. If it *was* intentionally cast that way, that really raises more questions than it answers, but frankly, if you can figure out how to make a spell that scars you with a map you should be able to make it update itself.

Actually, now that I think about it, that could apply to all other scar instances. As McGonagall asks if Dumbledore can remove the scar, we know it’s possible in some cases, so logically, if you can get rid of it entirely, why not change it? I mean, sure, it sounds painful, but it would only be a few tweaks, and hey, it’s a free map. Might as well.

Comment: Maybe it was a sort of magical tattoo. Dumbledore seems like the sort of person who'd get one, given how quirky he was. Or maybe he had an unfortunate incident with a Underground branding iron. Great answer!

Comment: British version of Sectumsmepra? JKR is British.